# XSL sorting of elements in order while also adding spaces

Tags: xml, sorting, xslt

I have a xsl that sorts elemets in order and I also wanted to add spaces after specific nodes
Example:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <fruits criteria="XXX">
        <color>XXX</color>
        <type>XXX</type>
        <taste>XXX</taste>
    </fruits>
    <veggies>
        <carrot>XXXX</carrot>
        <beetroot>XXX</beetroot>
        <pumpkin>XXX</pumpkin>
    </veggies>
    <something>
        <xxx>42343</xxx>
    </something>
</catalog>
```

XSl is

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="fruits">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="taste"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="color"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="veggies/* | fruits/* | something/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
        <xsl:if test="following-sibling::*">
            <xsl:text>&#x0A;</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Expected out put:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
    <fruits criteria="XXX">
        <type>XXX</type>
        <taste>XXX</taste>
        <color>XXX</color>    
    </fruits>

    <veggies>
        <carrot>XXXX</carrot>
        <beetroot>XXX</beetroot>
        <pumpkin>XXX</pumpkin>
    </veggies>

    <something>
        <xxx>42343</xxx>
    </something>
</catalog>
```

It doesn't add spaces but it works if I strip out the sorting xsl template. both sort and spacing doesn't work together. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have the white space creating in a template of the wrong match pattern and in general such stuff is easier in XSLT 1.0 where you can delegate tasks to a template of lower priority with `xsl:next-match`:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="fruits">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, type, taste, color"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/*[following-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:next-match/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

http://xsltransform.net/6pS1zDR.

With XSLT 1.0 you will have to name templates and use call-template instead of next-match:

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/fruits" name="fruits" priority="5">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="type"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="taste"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="color"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/fruits[following-sibling::*]" priority="5">
        <xsl:call-template name="fruits"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/*[following-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:call-template name="identity"/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

Finally, with XSLT 3 you can focus on writing only the two templates for the elements needing special treatment:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="3.0">

    <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="fruits">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, type, taste, color"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="catalog/*[following-sibling::*]">
        <xsl:next-match/>
        <xsl:text>&#10;&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```